# Making dissimilar item recommendations, best approach

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I have a binary matrix of items, movies people have and have not watched.

My task is to build a recommendation system that recommends unexpected movies to a user - movies that are dissimilar to the ones they usually watch.

I'm wondering what approach or approaches would be suitable for building recommendation engine like this?

My first thought was to create an item based collaborative filter recommender and look for items that have the greatest distance from one another, rather than the closest. But maybe there's a better way to go about this.